# Finding what's new in swift framework

Tags: swift, healthkit

I am using HealthKit for a Watch app and wanted to see what has been added since WatchOS 4.0. When I go to the documentation under API changes it lists none. Is there a way to filter the documentation to see what's available only for WatchOS 4.0? Or is there a list somewhere showing the changes? [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit) documentation for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, Apple broke their documentation viewer since they released iOS 11.

Archive.org thankfully has it saved. [Here you can see what frameworks have been added, modified, or removed in iOS 11](https://web.archive.org/web/20170726094257/https://developer.apple.com/documentation?changes=latest_minor). Specifically for HealthKit, you can scroll [through here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170727203512/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit?changes=latest_minor) and see a few methods in green and purple, which means they were added or modified respectively.